# Is string.ElementAt() O(1)?

Tags: c#, linq, string, ienumerable

Under remarks, [it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) says

> If the type of source implements IList, that implementation is used to obtain the element at the specified index. Otherwise, this method obtains the specified element.

[String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) does not implement `IList<T>`. Does that mean this will be an `O(n)` operation if I declare something like,

```
IEnumerable<char> myString = "stringy";
```

?

Comment: This leads to the interesting question of why `string` doesn't implement `IList<char>`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I thought about that too, but I assume it's because strings are immutable. Can't have those `Add` and `Remove` methods.

Comment: @Ralph IList<T> has a IsReadOnly property. And the mutation methods would be implemented explicitly(so they don't show up in `string` itself) and throw a `NotSupportedException`. Still I think it's a design mistake in .net to have no readonly interfaces for Collection/List.

Comment: But why do you use `ElementAt` on a string at all instead of just using the indexer?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Because I don't have a string, I have an `IEnumerable<char>`, which *might* happen to be a string. Or a List<char>, or an array, or what have you.

Comment: This may be stating the obvious, but `string` also supports indexing so `myString[x]` works and since Reflector shows this to an extern application I reckon it doesn't enumerate the sequence of characters.

Comment: @Brian: You are stating the obvious :) Like I said, I don't know the internal type, I just know that I have an IEnumerable that might happen to be a string. Yes, I could check it manually before calling `ElementAt()`, but that's an extra step I don't want to take every where. Could write my own extension... but... you know, just sucks when you have to do these little things because of one tiny little flaw in the standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ElementAt` when applied to a type which is a `string` will be an O(N) operation.  It does not implement `IList<char>` and hence `ElementAt` won't do any optimizations on it and instead enumerates through the `IEnumerable<char>` until it reaches the specified index.

Comment: There's no special case implementation for string? That sucks :(

Comment: @Ralph in general the LINQ methods do not implement special cases for concrete typse but instead for interfaces.

Comment: String is so common though! :p It's still special in my heart, even if linq won't recognize it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Since string is not implementing `IList` but `IEnumerable<char>` ElementAt will execute the following code:

```
using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
```

and GetEnumerator on string retrieves a `CharEnumerator` which is O(n) as you assumed.

If you want a better implementation create your own extension method

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static char ElementAt(this string input, int index)
    {
        if (index < input.Length) return input[index];
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

which I assume is O(1), but hard to tell since the index accessor on string is done in unsafe code.

Comment: Just FYI, your extension method is kind of useless if it extends only string ;)

Comment: You can rename it to ElementsAt, and it will pick your specific implementation before the Linq one.Then add specific versions as needed.